# Show only data from the first to last occuring month in a pivot table grouped by month and year with "Show items with no data" checked

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I want to show data in a pivot table, grouped by month and year, showing items for all months, including months without data. 
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.excel-university.com/show-pivottable-months-without-data/).
However, this doesn't work as I want when I additionally group by year.

Example:

```
2015/11/3
2016/1/7
2016/3/19
```

appears in the pivot table like this, if "Show items with no data" is not checked:

```
2015
    Nov    1
2016
    Jan    1
    Mar    1
```

If it is checked, it will show:

```
2015
    Jan    0
    Feb    0
    Mar    0
    Apr    0
    May    0
    Jun    0
    Jul    0
    Aug    0
    Sep    0
    Okt    0
    Nov    1
    Dec    0
2016
    Jan    1
    Feb    0
    Mar    1
    Apr    0
    May    0
    Jun    0
    Jul    0
    Aug    0
    Sep    0
    Okt    0
    Nov    0
    Dec    0
```

What I actually want is this:

```
2015
    Nov    1
    Dec    0
2016
    Jan    1
    Feb    0
    Mar    1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a direct fix, but would it be out of the question to put a value for 0 sales in December and February into your data? I don't know how your data is formatted, but even if it's daily, you could put in a value for the days 11/1 and 2/1 with 0 sales, which would count as 0 sales for the month.

This would allow the pivot table to pick up those months and display them, with "Show items with no data" unchecked.